# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id (someid) (id/) for fragment Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception

In my app, I have some fragments. From my activity using the below code I loaded the `Fragment` in the fragmentgroup for `Fragment`

```
FragmentManager fm;
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
f3 = new CustomerTransactionFragment();
ft.add(R.id.fragmentgroup,f3,"C");
ft.commit();
```

in the `CustomerTransactionFragment()`;

```
public class CustomerTransactionFragment extends SherlockFragment
{
      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customertransaction, container, false);
            return view;
        }
      @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         Fragment fragment = null;
           fragment = new CustomerSearchFragment();
           if (fragment != null) {
               FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.customertransaction_form_fragmentgroup, 
                                fragment).commit();
           }

    }
}
```

here `customertransaction`_form_fragmentgroup is  `LinearLayout` in `customertransaction.xml`  for loading the child `Fragment` like `CustomerSearchFragment`.

Because of length From `CustomerSearchFragment` i am only denoting essential code in below,

```
    ListView lv;
    ListAdapter adapter;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customerlist, container, false);
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        lv = (ListView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.ccustomerlist_form_ListViewcustomers);

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), dataList,
                R.layout.singlecustomerselect, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_ID,
                        TAG_PHONE }, new int[] { R.id.sincusname,
                        R.id.sincusid, R.id.sincusgsm });
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I don't include the code for setting the adapter.because there is no problem in loading the adapter. It shows the item perfectly and on item click also gets the current item selected. The problem occured when I tried to replace the current `Fragment` with new one in `customertransaction_form_fragmentgroup`,when the item click is performed.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "NAME:" + selname + "\nCODE:" + selcode
                                + "\nPHONE:" + selphno, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                  Fragment fragment = null;
                  fragment = new CustomerDetailDisplayFragment();
                   if (fragment != null) {
                       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.customertransaction_form_fragmentgroup, fragment).commit();
                   } 


            }
        });

}
```

**The log cat is given below**

```
03-19 09:05:08.156: W/dalvikvm(1761): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f040054 (com.noufal.posfragment:id/customertransaction_form_fragmentgroup) for fragment CustomerDetailDisplayFragment{405bf608 #0 id=0x7f040054}
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-19 09:05:08.176: E/AndroidRuntime(1761):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

)

please help to find solution.thanks in advance..

Comment: where do you have the container `R.id.customertransaction_form_fragmentgroup`??

Comment: in the  CustomerTransactionFragment.

Comment: well it says it can't find the container. You already have a cotainer in activity. you should just replace the same with a new framgent

Comment: fragments hosted by a activty. activity has a container with id `R.id.fragmentgroup` replace existing fragmgnt with a new one. What is that you don't understand. Do you have nested framgents??

Comment: yes..i have nested ones first R.id.fragmentgroup is replaced with R.id.customertransaction_form_fragmentgroup in which customerseach activity is hosted. from here i wnt to replace R.id.customertransaction_form_fragmentgroup with new fragment

Comment: Can Any One Help Me get Rid of this error....
[My Error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400641/fragmentmanager-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment?noredirect=

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whether `CustomerDetailDisplayFragment` having `View`. For example, have you assign layout for that `Fragment` (`CustomerDetailDisplayFragment`). if `View` is not created in next `Fragment` will throw exception.